# how to remove %20 at the end of the url in opencart using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

i have tried so many ways but none of seems working. in my site which built in opencart 1.5.4, i have so many url where %20 or whitespace are added in the last of url, i want to redirect those to right url for example"

wrong url: http://kinderwonderland.nl/brio%20
right url:http://kinderwonderland.nl/brio

can anyone help?

i have tried

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*?)(%20)+([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]

RedirectMatch 301 "^(.+?) +$

but nothing seems working.

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

# Begin Redirect 301
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*)\s$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]
# BEGIN OpenCart

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 weeks"
FileETag none

# END OpenCart


### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none



## INCREASE PAGE SPEED HTACCESS MODIFICATION ##
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent
</ifModule>
## END INCREASE PAGE SPEED HTACCESS MODIFICATION ##
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\s$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: i have added my htaccess if that can helps